# Change the text color of a native-styled combo box in qt (qml)

Tags: android, qt, combobox, qml

I am using a ComboBox from QtQuick.Controls 1.4. It looks good an android, but I want to change the text color.

So I try this:

```
ComboBox {
    id: list
    model: ListModel {
            ...
    }
    style: ComboBoxStyle {textColor:"white"}
}
```

Unfortunately, that changes the complete style of the combo box making it look more like a Combo box on the Desktop. How can I only change the color but keep the remaining style?

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a hack but you may be able to access the underlying style item via the `__style` property.

```
ComboBox
{
    id: list
    model: [ "Banana", "Apple", "Coconut" ]
    Component.onCompleted: {
        __style.textColor = "white"
    }
}
```

I am using Qt 5.2 so I do not have access to the `textColor` property. Therefore this may not work at all. Have a look at the ComboBox and ComboBoxStyle source files, located in `PathToQt/.../.../qml/QtQuick/Controls` to see how the style is implemented.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error: ```Error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "textColor"```